# Parsing Python textfile with tags

Tags: python, parsing, text, full-text-search, markup

I am parsing a 300 page document with python and I need to find out the attribute values of the `Response` element after the `ThisVal` element. There are multiple points where the `Response` element is used for `differentVals`, so I need to find out what is in the `Response` `elements` attribute value after finding the `ThisVal` element.

If it helps, the tokens are unique to `ThisVal`, but are different in every document.

```
11:44:49 <ThisVal Token="5" />
11:44:49 <Response Token="5" Code="123123" elements="x.one,x.two,x.three,x.four,x.five,x.six,x.seven" />
```

Comment: Remove the timestamps (e.g. with `awk`) and try it with http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.

Comment: thanks that is helpful, but the issue is to find it after "thisval" There are 100's of response tags, but I need the one that matches the particular element, IE "thisval"

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)? I've found it to be very useful for this kind of thing. Below is my attempt at a solution to your problem.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

document = """11:44:49 <ThisVal Token="5" />
11:44:49 <Response Token="5" Code="123123" elements="x.one,x.two,x.three,x.four,x.five,x.six,x.seven" />
"""

num = pp.Word(pp.nums)
colon = ":"

start = pp.Suppress("<")
end = pp.Suppress("/>")
eq = pp.Suppress("=")

tag_name = pp.Word(pp.alphas)("tag_name")

value = pp.QuotedString("\"")

timestamp = pp.Suppress(num + colon + num + colon + num)
other_attr = pp.Group(pp.Word(pp.alphas) + eq + value)

tag = start + tag_name + pp.ZeroOrMore(other_attr)("attr") + end

tag_line = timestamp + tag

thisval_found = False

for line in document.splitlines():

    result = tag_line.parseString(line)
    print("Tag: {}\nAttributes: {}\n".format(result.tag_name, result.attr))

    if thisval_found and tag_name == "Response":
        for a in result.attr:
            if a[0] == "elements":
                print("FOUND: {}".format(a[1]))

    thisval_found = result.tag_name == "ThisVal"
```